# Local convergence for $x_k = f(x_{k-1})$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n}$, given any $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can generate a sequence such that $x_{k} = f(x_{k-1})$ for $k \geq 1$. If for some $a$ , we have $\lim\limits_{ x \to a }f(x) = a$, does there exist some open neighborhood $N$ around $a$ and $x_{0} \in N$, such that $\lim\limits_{ k \to \infty }x_{k} = a$?

I am curious about this because I kind of want to take the limit on both side of $x_{k} = f(x_{k-1})$, and solve for the limits. However, this only works if we know $x_{k}$ is convergent in the first place, so I'm wondering about this case.

This statement is automatically true if $f$ is continuous at $a$, as we can set $x_{0} = a$. Also if we instead say $x_{0} \in N \setminus \{ x_{0} \}$, then taking f as the identity would make the statement false. However, I wonder in the stated way, is this true in general?

This is probably related to some dynamical system concepts, but unfortunately I don't have much experience in this area besides a basic course on ODE. I have looked at examples where a point is attractive and not stable, but that also did not lead me anywhere.

Comment: Try to look at fixed point theorems.

Comment: @Youem Thank you for the comment. Do you mean the Banach fixed point theorem? I don't think f is necessarily a contraction mapping even locally, so this might not be true?

Comment: you need to make your question precise. Are you fixing $x_0$ ? What do you mean by if we "know" $x_0 ?$ You can generate such sequence whether or not you "know" $x_0.$ Is $N$ given ? What is also N ? Are they the same ?

Comment: What about this function $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2\cdot x & \text{when } x \ne 0 \\ 
1 & \text{when } x=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Will it count as a counter-example?

Comment: @rtybase Thank you. This works. Mind putting this in the answer as well so I can mark this question as complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter-example:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 2\cdot x & \text{when } x \ne 0 \\  1 & \text{when } x=0 \end{matrix}\right.$$
for $a=0$. For any vicinity around $0$ and any initial $x_0$ in the vicinity, the sequence generated by $x_{k}=f(x_{k-1})$ will, eventually, "escape" the vicinity.